# opensearch ie & firefox generator

Tags: firefox, search, opensearch

i have some sites that i search frequently and i want to make a quick search for them (open search ) on my firefox and ie browsers, i dont find somthing that can generate a code that works in both ff and ie .. is there app/site that generates quicksearch buttons easy instad of messing with xml?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you are looking for: http://customsearchprovider.appspot.com.

Answer (score 0):

The following link works in Firefox.  Open http://mvinetwork.co.uk/opensearch and then you get a list of search providers on the search box drop-down menu. IE9 does not seem to support opensearch anymore.